# e.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//funciones varias y variables
...
...
...
 $(window).load(function() {
    loaded = true;
    isLoaded();
});


// mas funciones y variables
...
...
...
}); // end del document.ready
```

el error que me salta es el siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
>       at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument. (prrrcl-app.js:620)

Siento la línea 620 el `window.load`.

¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice que está en un `e.indexOf` y, en el código que has puesto, no hay ninguno, tendrías que añadir el resto del código con tal de ver dónde y por qué puede estar fallando

Comment: Que version de jquery estas utilizando? Probablemente sea la version ya que ahora es `$(window).on("load",function(){});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

el método `load` quedó obsoleto en la versión 1.8 y removido en la versión 3 y por esto ya no te va a funcionar en la 3.3.1, usar el siguiente código (como te mencionaron)

```
$(window).on("load",function(){});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias